# .htaccess FilesMatch to block php execution of php files with names containing uppcase letters

Tags: php, .htaccess

Could you please help me to find out a solution to block php execution of files that containing uppercase letters like: lx0m7WdDKIyz6s21XUPM.php or Ah22.php. those are backdoors/shels on my server and I have to block their execution until I find security leak. Operational php files are all lowercase.
I Am new to FilesMatch. this solution doesnt work

```
<FilesMatch "[A-Z]\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: `[A-Z]` would be _only_ uppercase letters. And since there is no quantifier either, this would only match files that have only _one_ uppercase letter followed by `.php` as name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `"^.*\[A-Z\].*\.php$"` this can be works for you... (check on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3y3SoP/1))